# How to use a library and a modified version of the same library together in a project?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Suppose there is a library consisting of some my_lib.c and my_lib.h

It is an open source standard library with thousands of users. However, For my project, I need to use that library for two different devices. One of the devices can use that library as it is, but another one needs to modify the read/write functions of that library and replace them with my_read() and my_write() functions.

Currently I've included two different versions of that library in my project, one original and another modified. However it means a lot of code duplication in the project, code size increase and non-acceptance by the community.

How do I solve this design problem in the most optimal way?

---

For more details (Loosing Generality here):

It is not a library it is linux Common Clock Framework, that is used to control clocks of two different SOC's at same time, one is host (whose clocks operations can use normal readl/writel) and another is slave connected via pcie (whose clocks need the mapped pcie_read/pcie_write that we have implemented).

Comment: Provide a configuration mechanism that takes pointers to functions to reroute the calls to the `pcie_read()` and `pcie_write()` when appropriate, leaving pointers to the normal `read()` and `write()` functions in place as the default.  This assumes that you'll preserve the API.  Then write the main code so that the correct set of pointers to functions is used to invoke the low-level routine.

Comment: I'd 2nd Jonathan's suggestion.  I've used exactly this method in the past and it works fairly well.  Some platforms will show a slight performance hit, but it's usually pretty trivial in impact.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what those `pcie_read()` and `pcie_write()` provide on top of usual `readl()` and `writel()`.

Comment: @0andriy The Second SOC is a companion chip that is connected to the Original SOC via PCIe interface (runtime iATU mappings). So the addresses can't be read directly with `readl()` and `writel()`